# Message not being sent to all connections Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to write a program that allows for multiple connections and the server operator can send messages to all the connected clients. I have sorted out the problem of allowing multiple connections using simple threading, now my problem is the message doesn't send to all the connected clients all at once, I have to send the message multiple times to send it to ever client.

```
def send(add, conn, port, s):
    while True:       
        message = raw_input("Message: ")
        add.send(message)

def server(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(10))
    print "Waiting for connections..."
    while True:        
        a,b = s.accept()
        print b, "connected"
        connections.append(b)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=send, args=(a, b, port, s))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how TCP works. There's no broadcast facility. If you need to send the same message to multiple connected clients, you have to do it for each socket.

Comment: How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: I have actually tried that. It only sends the message to one of the connected clients. That is why I am so puzzled.

Comment: Maybe because you store addresses and not sockets in that list.

Comment: It does the same thing, it sends the message twice (because I have two connections to the server) but only to one client at a time.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks Mr.Fetissov :D